# HTML tags not working in certain browsers

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser, form-submit

I have an HTML form and the submit button for find employees does not work in Firefox, but does in IE and chrome. Any suggestions or ideas why this is so?

```
 <form action="employees.cfm" name="limit_options" id="a"  method="post" >

   <cfoutput>

    <input  type="hidden"
     name="LV_ALPHA" 
     id="LV_ALPHA"
     value="" 
    />

    <th>

     <input  type = "text" 
     name = "LV_VNDR_NAME"  
     value = "#htmlEditFormat(LV_VNDR_NAME)#"
     size = "15"
     maxlength = "15"
     height    = "200px" />
    >
   </th>
  <th>

    <input  type = "text" 
     name = "LV_VNDR_NAME"  
     value = "#htmlEditFormat(LV_VNDR_NAME)#"
     size = "10"
     maxlength = "6"
    />
  </th>
  <th colspan="3">

    <input  type = "text" 
     name = "LV_ASSIGNED_USERID"  
     value = "#htmlEditFormat(LV_ASSIGNED_USERID)#"
     size = "10"
     maxlength = "7"
    />
  </th>

   <th colspan="7">
    <!-- Problem with this button in firefox -->
    <input  type = "submit"
     name = "LV_Submit5"  
     value = "Find Employees"
    />

     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

     <input  type="reset" value="Clear">

  </th>
</cfoutput>             

                </form>
```

Comment: "does not work in firefox". What happens exactly? I tried it and when I click the button in FF the form is submitted.

Comment: Is the `>` after "height    = "200px" />" intentional?

Comment: you should check that extra `>` @ChiChan mentioned

Comment: How is this a ColdFusion question?

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `<th>` as a child element of a `<form>`.

Some browsers (Firefox certainly) are known to error recover from the error of interleaving forms with tables by moving the form so it appears just after the table (while leaving the inputs behind).

This explains your problem (if the button isn't in the form, it won't submit it).

Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org). Write valid markup.